# Angular2 ng-bootstrap Tabs and Accordion

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using Angular2 and ng-bootstrap. I took the NgbAccordion and NgbTabset examples from [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion). They are working well functionally, but their styles are the problem. Tabs don't change to active when clicked and the panels in accordion have no style completely. What could be the problem?

```
<ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="true" activeIds="1">
  <ngb-panel id="1" title="Simple">
    <template ngbPanelContent>
       ...
    </template>
  </ngb-panel>
  <ngb-panel id="2">
    <template ngbPanelTitle>
      <span>&#9733; <b>Fancy</b> title &#9733;</span>
    </template>
    <template ngbPanelContent>
       ...
    </template>
  </ngb-panel>
  <ngb-panel id="3" title="Disabled" [disabled]="true">
    <template ngbPanelContent>
      ...
    </template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

Comment: You should post your relevant code, or, even better, a code snippet...

Comment: And, above all, why don't use native Bootstrap Tabs and Accordions? :-) For a tabs and accordions example see: http://codepen.io/TrailRunner65/pen/kqiFI

Comment: This example requires jQuery. It was problematic when I used jQuery with AngularJS. Is it safe to use it with Angular2?

Comment: Both Angular1 and Angular2 are fully compatible with jQuery. 
However, Angular doesn’t depend on jQuery. In fact, the Angular source contains an embedded lightweight alternative: jqLite. Still, when Angular detects the presence of a jQuery version in your page, it uses that full jQuery implementation in lieu of jqLite.

Comment: I added both jquery and bootstrap.min.js but still the example not working. It does not toggle the panels.

Comment: Which example? Try starting from the official docs (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs, https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion)...

Comment: This example: http://codepen.io/TrailRunner65/pen/kqiFI 
The docs are for Angular1 not Angular2?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't notice the '2' after Angular... :-( Sorry again!